# Github actions, setting gem username from secrets: Please CGI escape your usernames and passwords before setting them for authentication

Tags: ruby, github, github-actions

I'm trying to setup Github actions to run our specs however we use a private gem server which requires a password. I have [added a secret](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets) and then [set a ENV](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/using-environment-variables) to the value of the secret.

However I get the following error from bundler:

> "Please CGI escape your usernames and passwords before setting them for authentication".

I can see there this happens in the [bundler source](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/commit/0611c4bea9a5da42f668af64ae31d7628c640c5e). It seems to be an issue with the URI.

I do not get this error when following the same procedure locally or on our current CI server.

This is the workflow:

```
name: Ruby

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up Ruby 2.6
      uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: 2.6.x
    - name: Build and test with RSpec
      env:
        gems_password: '${{ secrets.GEMS_PASSWORD }}'
      run: |        
        gem install bundler
        bundle config gems.example.eu gems:$${GEMS_PASSWORD}
        bundle install
        bundle exec rspec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ENV only needs one `$`:

```
bundle config gems.example.eu gems:${GEMS_PASSWORD}
```

The double `$` as copied from the previous CI's configuration was perhaps an string interpolation feature.